# using undo/redo in Swing for an MVC model?

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, undo-redo

I have an MVC model,and Im trying to add an undo/redo feature to it.
User can place a number in a JTextField, and when they click the UNDO button, it should be erased.
I have provided the code for my classes that implement this. The error I get is at the bottom.

The Control package:

## ButtonnGUIControl.java

package control;

/**
 * This class will control the button actions of the GUI.It implements the actionListener() method 
 *  and based on the button that was clicked, it initializes the 
 * corresponding component in the model class.
 * 
 */

```
public class ButtonGUIControl implements ActionListener{
private SudokuModel model;
private ButtonGUI bgui;
final UndoManager manager = new UndoManager();



public ButtonGUIControl(SudokuModel model) {
    this.model = model;
}

/*This method will listen for user events, and act accordingly
 * */

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    try {   
         if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Check My Answer!")){

            model.checkGame();
        }


         else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Undo")){

             try {

                    manager.undo();
                } catch (CannotUndoException ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
                finally {
                    //updateButtons();
                }                   
         }
         else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Redo")){

             manager.redo();
             System.out.println("e.getActionCommand().equals redo");
         }

        //otherwise, it simply places the selected number in the grid
        else{

            model.setNumber(Integer.parseInt(e.getActionCommand()));
        }

    } catch (NumberFormatException e1) {}

    catch (IOException e1) {}
    catch (CannotUndoException ex) {
        System.out.println("Unable to undo: " + ex);
        ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    catch (CannotRedoException ex) {
        System.out.println("Unable to redo: " + ex);
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }    

}

public void undoableEditHappened(UndoableEditEvent evt) {

    manager.addEdit(evt.getEdit());

    //bgui.updateButtons();

}
```

}

---

In the view package:
ButtonGUI.java

I add an actionListner to the buttons:

RedoBttn.addActionListener(buttonController);

UndoBttn.addActionListener(buttonController);

---

In the Grid.java, which extends the JTextField:

```
public class Grid extends JTextField {
private int x;       
private int y; 

final UndoManager manager = new UndoManager();


public Grid(int x, int y) {
    super("");
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    getDocument().addUndoableEditListener(manager);



    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 40));
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GREEN));
    setOpaque(true);
}


public void setNumber(int number, boolean userInput)  {


    if(number > 0 & !userInput){
        setText(""+number);
        setEditable(false);


    }

    //These set of numbers are the only ones that the user can undo/redo
    else if (number > 0 & userInput){
        setText(""+number);
        setEditable(true);
}
    else
    setText("");
```

---

I also added a mouse listenr to each of the JTextFields in another class in the view package.
So I think I have the undo/redo structure right.
When I run the program, I can select a number and place it in a JTextField(grid), but as soon as I hit "undo" I get the following exception:

```
    javax.swing.undo.CannotUndoException
at javax.swing.undo.UndoManager.undo(UndoManager.java:411)
at control.ButtonGUIControl.actionPerformed(ButtonGUIControl.java:76)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2713)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:707)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:680)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:678)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:677)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

and line 76 is where I call:

```
    manager.undo()
```

in a try/catch block.

Any idea whats wrong? Is it my undo/redo implementation or  something else?

Thanks!!!

Comment: I tried a print statement on 

`evt.getEdit();`

and it is:

`[javax.swing.text.GapContent$RemoveUndo@55cc9339 hasBeenDone: true alive: true]`


`[javax.swing.text.GapContent$InsertUndo@69d5af30 hasBeenDone: true alive: true]`

Is this correct? However I still get the exception...

Comment: and when I do:
 `manager.getUndoPresentationName()` it returns "undo", NOT "undoAddition"

 so I think the events are being added to the edit list, its just when I try to undo it doesnt work.

Answer (score 3):

Try wrapping `manager.undo();` like this:

```
if(manager.canUndo())
    manager.undo();
```

I suspect the default UndoListener implementation of `JTextField` doesn't add system updates (ie. calling `setText(""+number);` to the undo queue) - only updates from the UI.

**EDIT**

After doing some testing, it seems that the `setText("")` function does add undos to the `UndoManager`, so that's not the problem you're running into.  So you can prevent the error by making sure there's any undo-able actions to undo;  But if you're not getting any undo-able actions in your `UndoManager`, the problem is probably happening somewhere else in the code.

Comment: but what if the if-block is never true? Yes I think an event is not propagating through all the classes. IS there a way around this?

Comment: @greg I created an example and the `UndoManager` works fine with `setText()`, so that's not the problem.  The `manager.canUndo()` check will prevent an attempted undo when there isn't anything to undo - the other problem must be somewhere else in the code (that you haven't posted).  Can you create an SSCCE recreating the problem?  I can post my code if it would help.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, consider [`JFormattedTextField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html). By default, the *reset-field-edit* action is bound to the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key, but you can bind the action to another key as required, say `KeyEvent.VK_Z`, as shown in [*How to Use Actions*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html). For cross-platform compatibility, use `getMenuShortcutKeyMask()`, mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8105344/230513).